# How to display all the fields in a array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-markers

I would like to display the content of an array in a Googlemap bubble.
I wonder why the following code is not working properly, since I only see the title but not the news in the bubble.

```
function addMarker(latitude, longitude, title, news)
{
    var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude));

    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click',function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(title, news);
    });

    map.addOverlay(marker);
}

function init()
{
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
    {   
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map")); 
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(centerLatitude, centerLongitude), startZoom);

        for (id = 0; id < markers.length; ++id)
        {
            addMarker(markers[id].latitude, markers[id].longitude, markers[id].title, markers  [id].news); //
        }
    }
}

window.onload = init;
window.onunload = GUnload;
```

And this is the array structure:

```
var markers = [
{
    'latitude': 56.7382105,
    'longitude': 12.8584020,
    'title': 'Hallo Planet',
    'news': 'blaaaa blaaaa blaaaa.'
},
{
    'latitude': 62.6549167,
    'longitude': 16.6354329,
    'title': 'Hallo World',
    'news': 'bla bla bla.'
},
];
```

I tried also without the comma after the curly bracket `}` but the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's "openInfoWindowHtml" accepts two parameters, but not those. See [their documentation on this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.openInfoWindowHtml).

To format a title *and* body in that info window, you need to combine both "title" and "news" elements into one string (with HTML formatting). Or, you could use "openInfoWindow" with a pre-made DOM node ready-to-go instead. Try:

```
marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<h1>" + title + "</h1> " + news);
```

Does that work better?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's better, indeed

Comment: Cool. Be sure to accept the answer (like Yoshi described above), please.